# Know which element was touched with React Native's PanResponder?

Tags: react-native

Im making a drag and drop with the PanResponder but I only want part of a component to be the 'target' which initiates the drag. Many elements are contained within a ScrollView, and dragging on the elements outside of the 'target' should scroll as usual.

```
const Dragger = () => {
    return (
        <View {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Text>Drag me</Text>
                <Text>Im not draggable</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Text>Drag me</Text>
                <Text>Im not draggable</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const Parent = () => {
    return(
        <ScrollView>
            <Text>Stuff</Text>
            <Dragger />
            <Text>Stuff</Text>
        <ScrollView/>
    )
}
```

Can this be done or do I need to attach multiple `panHandlers` to each `<Text>Drag me</Text>`?

From the docs I see there is a `nativeEvent.target` which returns "The node id of the element receiving the touch event", however it's just a number so Im not sure how to use it?

Would I need to find out the node IDs of the `<Text>Drag me</Text>` elements and see if the number that came back is in that list?

UPDATE: Here is a more visual demo of what Im trying to do:

https://snack.expo.io/@jamesweblondon/rude-pretzel

I need PanResponder drag events on the grey boxes, but not on the text inputs:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from "react-native";

const items = new Array(50).fill(0).map((item, index) => {
  return {
    id: index,
    backgroundColor: `rgb(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${
      index * 5
    }, ${132})`,
  };
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  item: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: 200,
    width: "100%",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  input: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 20,
    height: "100%",
    flex: 1,
  },
  handle: {
    display: "flex",
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    height: "80%",
    width: 100,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <View
            style={[styles.item, { backgroundColor: item.backgroundColor }]}
          >
            <View style={styles.handle} />
            <TextInput style={styles.input} defaultValue={item.id} />
          </View>
        );
      })}
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to set `pointerEvents="none"` on components you want to make non-draggable?

Comment: Can you provide an visual example of your component? I already made something like it but with positions of the component

Comment: @ivanmoskalev That wont work for me, I need it to respond to other touch events eg focusing on an input or scrolling.

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior Ive updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started your question with some snippets that I couldn't find in the link you posted, so I started from that and created a fork.
So in order to get the PanResponder drag events on the grey boxes, but not on the text inputs you should do like this on your item component:

```
<View style={[styles.item, { backgroundColor: item.backgroundColor }]} >
    <View style={styles.handle} {...panResponder.panHandlers} />
    <TextInput style={styles.input}>{item.id}</TextInput>
</View>
```

For the PanResponder i used the default config from https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder#example

Here's an [update](https://snack.expo.io/@vert3x/stack_61546717) on your code to try it.

Hope this helps! Tell me if this isn't working for you.